# How to display time when page is created and edited

Tags: pages, page-template, date-time, timestamp

On posts I use this:

Time created

`<?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?>`

Edited (updated)

`<?php the_modified_time('Y-m-d'); ?>`

It works fine on posts, but on page template it displays just created time, modified (update) time is blank.

Question 1:
**How to show modified time on pages too?**

Question 2:
Also I need to display both times on category, tag and author pages. Using codes above I get those times, but from last post on current page, and I would like to get times from first post on current browsing page.
I have default post order (latest first), so I need latest post's times, which is first post on current page, and like I said I get times of last post on current page.

**How to get created / modified time of first post on current browsing page on category, tags, archive?**

**Update**

I need to display created and modified time outside of the loop.

Comment: both functions have to be used within the loop - what is your full code, and where are you using the functions?

Comment: Yes, I used them outside of the loop. How to get times outside the loop?